# Error when using xunit with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.1.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, xunit

When i use `xunit` with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.1.0`, I get following error(Without mvc there is no problem):

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or ass embly 'Microsoft.DotNet.InternalAbstractions,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'

`project.json`

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "testRunner": "xunit",
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0-*",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "xunit": "2.2.0-beta2-build3300",
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost": "1.1.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0-*"
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": "portable-net451+win8"
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: did you try to add "Microsoft.DotNet.InternalAbstractions": "1.0.0" in your test project.json ?

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. Could you write an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix it add **"Microsoft.DotNet.InternalAbstractions": "1.0.0"** in your test project.json :

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "testRunner": "xunit",
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0-*",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "xunit": "2.2.0-beta2-build3300",
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost": "1.1.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0-*",

    "Microsoft.DotNet.InternalAbstractions": "1.0.0"
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": "portable-net451+win8"
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```